# xml tags passed as arguments to xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tags

*How to modify the below xsl to process parameters whose value is tags. Instead of using w:p and w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val i will be passing them as args*

**Actual XSl**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml"
>
<xsl:param name="styleName"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="w:p"/>
<xsl:template match="w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val[matches(., concat('^(',$styleName,')$'),'i')]]"> 
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:ve="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml">

<xsl:param name="styleName" select="'articletitle'"/>
<xsl:param name="para" select="'//w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val[matches(.,concat('^(',$styleName,')$')]]'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">                
         <xsl:for-each select="$para">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
         </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: You should get used to give information about which version of xslt and which processor you are using. In this case, the answer is valid only if you are using XSLT 2.0**

This is not a complete answer, but you can start by looking at this approach:

Try using local-name and in-scope-prefixes (only available in XSLT 2.0) to match a node dynamically.

Here you have an example template to replace your empty template:

```
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()=substring-after($para,':') and in-scope-prefixes(.)[.=substring-before($para,':')]]"/>
```

For the second part of the expression ($parastyle), I can only think about writing your own function to evaluate it dynamically.

I'll try to post an example of such a function later on.

Comment: Thanks Carl...I have modified the Required xsl code. Please take a look ....I am looking forward for ur reply for the second part of expression.....

Answer (score 0):

I fugured out the problem in my coding, is in second line,

```
<xsl:param name="para" select="'//w:p[w:pPr/w:pStyle/@w:val[matches(.,concat('^(',$styleName,')$')]]'"/>
```

Since i have given the quotes in select attribute the value has been considered as string instead of xpath expression.